# regex in a multi match

Tags: java, regex

Can any of you help me out please? I have a string downloaded to "**result**" as follows:

```
DrawDate,Ball 1,Ball 2,Ball 3,Ball 4,Ball 5,Ball 6,Bonus Ball,Ball Set,Machine27-Feb-2013,2,24,14,23,20,30,22,6,MERLIN23-Feb-2013,31,25,32,2,30,16,36,5,MERLIN20-Feb-2013,36,45,3,6,44,48,47,8,MERLIN16-Feb-2013,7,27,48,46,39,20,49,6,ARTHUR13-Feb-2013,6,49,23,29,14,20,48,8,MERLIN09-Feb-2013,10,8,34,40,27,41,48,7,MERLIN06-Feb-2013,9,18,10,16,27,42,43,6,ARTHUR02-Feb-2013,2,13,14,21,12,30,39,7,ARTHUR30-Jan-2013,10,9,43,48,47,24,5,5,ARTHUR26-Jan-2013,2,6,21,29,47,34,11,5,ARTHUR
23-Jan-2013,10,6,32,24,41,14,29,8,MERLIN19-Jan-2013,35,5,9,13,39,16,11,7,ARTHUR16-Jan-2013,13,38,47,12,35,5,45,3,MERLIN12-Jan-2013,3,11,27,24,12,7,13,8,ARTHUR09-Jan-2013,48,39,24,21,5,25,32,6,MERLIN05-Jan-2013,15,37,10,21,17,47,2,5,ARTHUR02-Jan-2013,37,20,30,21,7,9,42,7,MERLIN29-Dec-2012,40,31,6,37,8,48,36,5,GUINEVERE26-Dec-2012,3,11,49,39,47,17,34,6,LANCELOT22-Dec-2012,34,28,4,44,43,14,13,4,LANCELOT
```

Then using the **regex** below:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(Machine|GUINEVERE|LANCELOT|ARTHUR|MERLIN)(.*?)(GUINEVERE|LANCELOT|ARTHUR|MERLIN)"); 

Matcher m = p.matcher(result);

while (m.find())
{
matchesList.add(m.group()); 
}
```

This is what come out to my **listview**:

```
1, Machine27-Feb-2013,2,24,14,23,20,30,22,6,LANCELOT

2, MERLIN20-Feb-2013,36,45,3,6,44,48,47,8,GUINEVER

3, ARTHUR13-Feb-2013,6,49,23,29,14,20,48,8,MERLIN
```

But the **regex misses out every even line**:

```
1, Machine27-Feb-2013,2,24,14,23,20,30,22,6,LANCELOT

2, 23-Feb-2013,31,25,32,2,30,16,36,5,

3, MERLIN20-Feb-2013,36,45,3,6,44,48,47,8,GUINEVER

4, 16-Feb-2013,7,27,48,46,39,20,49,6,

5, ARTHUR13-Feb-2013,6,49,23,29,14,20,48,8,MERLIN

6, 09-Feb-2013,10,8,34,40,27,41,48,7,
```

This is what I'm after:

```
1, 27-Feb-2013,2,24,14,23,20,30,22,6

2, 23-Feb-2013,31,25,32,2,30,16,36,5

3, 20-Feb-2013,36,45,3,6,44,48,47,8

4, 16-Feb-2013,7,27,48,46,39,20,49,6

5, 13-Feb-2013,6,49,23,29,14,20,48,8

6, 09-Feb-2013,10,8,34,40,27,41,48,7
```

This works in **C#** `"(?s)(?<=Machine|GUINEVERE|LANCELOT|ARTHUR|MERLIN).*?(GUINEVERE|LANCELOT|ARTHUR|MERLIN)"`
but **not** in **Java**,

I've tried loads of ways from the net to no avail. Tried **^** and **$** but don't understand how to work?

Comment: The sample text you supplied is all in *one* line, while you later state that the regex failed on every even line. Which one is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "(machine|GUINEVERE|...)" parts of your regex are capturing groups. This means that (1) they are included in the results and (2) the following match starts *after* them.

In the c# version you are using the "Zero-width positive lookbehind" grouping for the first machine block ("(?<=...)"), which helps. Now you just need to use the zero-width positive lookahead for the trailing group. This changes the regex to this:

```
(?<=Machine|GUINEVERE|LANCELOT|ARTHUR|MERLIN)(.*?)(?=GUINEVERE|LANCELOT|ARTHUR|MERLIN)
```

Which *almost* does what you want. It still produces trailing commas and a leading whitespace in the output. So change the regex to this:

```
(?<=Machine|GUINEVERE|LANCELOT|ARTHUR|MERLIN)\\s*(.*?),?(?=GUINEVERE|LANCELOT|ARTHUR|MERLIN)
```

and access "m.group(1)" instead of "m.group()". This way you only get the part matched by the "(.*?)".

An alternative for this particular example would be to do

```
String[] parts = result.split("[\\s,]*(Machine|GUINEVERE|LANCELOT|ARTHUR|MERLIN)[\\s,]*");
```

and discard the first result ("DrawDate, ...").

Comment: So ?<= means look after. and the ?= means look up to is that right?

Comment: @user2070354: See the API docs of the "Pattern" class: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html . It contains a pretty good description of the syntax.